# gui library for smfl when using c#

Tags: sfml, cegui

There exists [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is a nice GUI library, useable for SFML. The issue is now that there are C# bindings for SFML but not for CEGUI available -as it seems...

Is there any other GUI library out there, working together with SFML, which I could use in C#?

I'd like to avoid to jump to c++ only for the reason that there is no GUI library available...

Thanks

Comment: ok, http://www.swig.org/index.php might be alternative to generate wrappers...

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for it, but I stummbled across this one in my search for a GUI library to use with the SFML .Net bindings: [gwen-dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/gwen-dotnet/)